# How could I use limit and offset with pagedlist to paginate in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I'm using `PagedList` to paginate but it need to has all records in a list and then  make the pagination and it will waste a long time to render the page, so, I want to use LIMIT and OFFSET with PagedLit to make a real pagination and waste a short time.

How could I use PagedList with LIMIT and OFFSET to create a real pagination ?

trying

**Model**

```
public class SearchUsuarioModel{

    public IPagedList<UpUsuarioAdminModel> listaModel               { get; set; } //list model
    public IPagedList<Usuario> listaObject                          { get; set; } //list all objects

    //Status
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> status                       { get; set; }    
    public int statusSelected                                       { get; set; }

    public String nome                                              { get; set; }
    public String role                                              { get; set; }
    public int limit                                                { get; set; }
    public int offset                                               { get; set; }

    public int pageSize                                             { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber                                           { get; set; }

    public SearchUsuarioModel(){
        listaModel = new List<UpUsuarioAdminModel>().ToPagedList(1, 50);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult viewAllAdmin(int? page, String nome, String role, int? offSet){

        //model
        SearchUsuarioModel model = new SearchUsuarioModel();
        model.nome = nome;
        model.role = role;
        model.limit = 3;
        model.offset = offSet ?? 0;
        model.pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        model.pageSize = model.limit;

        //listas
        IList<Usuario> _listaObject = new List<Usuario>();
        IList<UpUsuarioAdminModel> _listaModel = new List<UpUsuarioAdminModel>();

        UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();
        try{            

           _listaObject = dao.findAllOffset(model.limit, model.offset);

        } catch (Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("viewAllAdmin UsuarioController: " + e.Message);
        }

        if (_listaObject.Count > 0){
            foreach (Usuario u in _listaObject){
                UpUsuarioAdminModel m = new UpUsuarioAdminModel();
                m.id = u.id;
                m.nome = u.nome;
                m.email = u.email;
                m.roleSelected = u.role.ToString();
                m.statusDesc = u.status == 1 ? "Ativo" : "Inativo";

                m.contrato = u.imgContrato;
                if (u.contato != null){
                    //Debug.WriteLine("Telefone: " + string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.contato.telefone1));
                    m.telefone1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.contato.telefone1) ? "" : u.contato.telefone1;
                }
                _listaModel.Add(m);
            }
        }

        model.listaModel = _listaModel.ToPagedList(model.pageNumber, model.limit);
        model.listaObject = dao.findAll().ToPagedList(model.pageNumber, model.limit);
        return View(model);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-red center-block">
    <div class="panel-heading bg-red clearfix">
        <strong>Usuários do sistema</strong>
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.ActionLink("Novo", "addUsuarioAdmin", "Usuario", new { Class = "text-white glyphicon glyphicon-plus" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped table-hover" id="tableView">
            <thead class="CabecalhoTabela">
                <tr>
                    <th>#ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Perfil</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Controles</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="conteudoTabela">
                @foreach (UpUsuarioAdminModel m in Model.listaModel){
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.nome)</td>
                        <td class="text-lowercase">@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.email)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.telefone1)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.roleSelected)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.statusDesc)</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink(" ", "editUsuarioAdmin", "Usuario", new { id = EncodingParams.encode(Convert.ToString(@m.id)) }, new { Class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil", title = "editar" })

                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.contrato))
                            {
                                @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Download", "Usuario", new { id = EncodingParams.encode(Convert.ToString(@m.id)) }, new { Class = "glyphicon glyphicon-file", title = "Contrato" })
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        Pagina @Model.listaObject.PageNumber de @Model.listaObject.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.listaObject, page => Url.Action("viewAllAdmin", new { page = Model.pageNumber, offSet = Model.offset }))
    </div>
</div>
```

**DAO**

```
public IList<Usuario> findAll(){
        ISession _session = getSession();
        IList<Usuario> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Usuario u ORDER BY u.id")            
            .List<Usuario>();
        return list;
    }

    public IList<Usuario> findAllOffset(int limit, int offset){
        ISession _session = getSession();
        IList<Usuario> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Usuario u ORDER BY u.id")
            .SetFirstResult(offset)
            .SetMaxResults(limit)
            .List<Usuario>();
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: `.ToPagedList()` internally uses `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to return only the required number of records, but you need to pass an `IQueryable<T>` to it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry, I don't understand what you said. Could you explain me ?

Comment: `.ToPagedList()` takes an `IQueryable<T>` (for example `var model = db.Usuarios;) and based on the 1st and 2nd parameters uses `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to update the SQL statement to use `OFFSET` and LIMIT` so that executing it returns only the x number the records you need. There is not really much point using `IPagedList()` if you going to write you own SQL statements to use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`

Comment: @StephenMuecke using `IQueryable<T>` how could I do with HTML to paginate, I mean the pagination url ? `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.listaObject, page => Url.Action("viewAllAdmin", new { page = Model.pageNumber, offSet = Model.offset }))`

Comment: `IPagedList()` is not really designed to work with view models, just your data model(s). The typical code would be `IQueryable<Usuario> usarios = db.Usuarios; model.listaObject = usarios.ToPagedList(page, 3);`

Comment: And in the view its just `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.listaObject, page => Url.Action("viewAllAdmin", new { page })`